# Unity 5 renderer.material.setTexture("_PARALLAXMAP"); Won't change the heightmap

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, perlin-noise

So I have been working on a piece of code that generates a perlin noise texture and applies it to a plane in order to create waves. But I can't get it to set the heightmap texture of the material. I have included `material.EnableKeyword("_PARALLAXMAP");` but it does nothing. I have tried this with the normal map as well, without results. Here's the full code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;    

public class NoiseGenerator : MonoBehaviour {
    private Texture2D noiseTex;
    private float x = 0.0F;
    private float y = 0.0F;
    public int scale = 10;
    private Color[] pixels;
    public float speed;
    public float move = 0.0F;
    void Start () {
        Renderer render = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        noiseTex = new Texture2D(scale,scale);
        render.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
        render.material.EnableKeyword("_PARALLAXMAP");
        render.material.SetTexture("_PARALLAXMAP", noiseTex);
        pixels = new Color[noiseTex.width * noiseTex.height];
    }
    void Update () {
        float y = 0.0F;
        while (y < noiseTex.height)
        {
            float x = 0.0F;
            while (x < noiseTex.width)
            {
                float xCoord = move + x / noiseTex.width * scale;
                float yCoord = move + y / noiseTex.height * scale;
                float sample = Mathf.PerlinNoise(xCoord, yCoord);
                pixels[Mathf.RoundToInt(y) * noiseTex.width + Mathf.RoundToInt(x)] = new Color(sample, sample, sample);
                x++;
            }
            y++;
        }
        noiseTex.SetPixels(pixels);
        noiseTex.Apply();
        move = move + speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the actual name of the texture parameter in the shader `_PARALLAXMAP` ?

Comment: According to unity's site it is, and I have tried other variations such as _parallaxmap, _ParallaxMap, _BumpMap, _NormalMap. Nothing works.

Comment: Only setting it as `_MainTex` works.

Comment: Which values exist will entirely depend on the shader in question.  In my own code I've been able to use "_SecondaryTexture" because the shader I was using *had that property* and I know it did, because I wrote the shader.

Comment: is there an initial texture applied in the heigtmap slot? which shader is being used?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a Material that use this Parallax variant to notify Unity about you need this.
This can be used in the scene or include in the resource folder.
If not Unity omit this on build how unused.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
ur_material.SetFloat("_Parallax",[value])
```